# .htaccess redirect to public folder, exclude subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory, subdomain

I have a PHP MVC website, the root needs to be redirected to public folder.

www folder includes:

```
- app
- public
- subdom/subdomain
```

subdomain folder is **subdomain.website.com**

app folder is restricted with **Options -Indexes**

I need to redirect to public folder, but not if I'm accessing subdomain.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

This will always get me into public folder but I can't access my subdomain.

I can always either access my subdomain or be redirected to public folder but even when I want to access my subdomain.

This is default .htaccess file in the www folder on Wedos webhosting.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) domains/%2/$1 [DPI]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdom/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdom/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdom/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) subdom/%2/$1 [DPI]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^subdom/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]
```

How do I exclude subdomains from the redirect?

**website.com** should be **website.com/public**

**subdomain.website.com** should remain that way - it should not be **website.com/public**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `RewriteCond` before 2 rules that deal with `/public` to check current host name:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great. I couldnt wrap my head around it. Does the condition say "if there's no subdomain" ?

Comment: Conditions says that apply rule only for `website.com` or `www.website.com`